# Prevent ComboBox editing in StyledItemDelegate

Tags: python, pyqt, pyqt5

I am trying to make everything shown by the current code un-editable.

Previous searches all suggest either modifying the flags() function of the model or using the setEditTriggers of the table. I do both in this code, but neither of them work.

Looking at a widget-by-widget case, I can find readonly modes for LineEdit and others, but not for ComboBox. So I can not even modify the delegate to force the readonly constraint, not that I would necessarily like to do it this way.

EDIT: to clarify, when I say I want the user to not be able to 'edit' I mean that he shouldn't be able to change the state of the widget in any way. E.g. he won't be able to click on a ComboBox (or at least changing the current selected item/index).

```py
from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtWidgets
import sys


class MyWindow(QtWidgets.QWidget):
    def __init__(self, *args):
        super().__init__(*args)
        tableview = TableView()
        layout = QtWidgets.QVBoxLayout(self)
        layout.addWidget(tableview)
        self.setLayout(layout)


class Delegate(QtWidgets.QStyledItemDelegate):
    def __init__(self, model):
        super().__init__()
        self.model = model

    def createEditor(self, parent, option, index):
        widget = QtWidgets.QComboBox(parent)
        widget.addItems(['', 'Cat', 'Dog'])
        return widget

    def setModelData(self, widget, model, index):
        self.model.setData(index, widget.currentIndex())


class Model(QtCore.QAbstractTableModel):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        QtCore.QAbstractTableModel.__init__(self, parent=parent)
        self.value = 0

    def flags(self, index):
        return QtCore.Qt.ItemIsEnabled

    def data(self, index, role=QtCore.Qt.DisplayRole):
        if not index.isValid() or role != QtCore.Qt.DisplayRole:
            return QtCore.QVariant()
        return QtCore.QVariant(self.value)

    def setData(self, index, value, role=QtCore.Qt.EditRole):
        self.value = value
        print("data[{}][{}] = {}".format(index.row(), index.column(), value))
        return True

    def rowCount(self, parent=QtCore.QModelIndex()):
        return 1

    def columnCount(self, parent=QtCore.QModelIndex()):
        return 1


class TableView(QtWidgets.QTableView):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super().__init__(parent)
        self.model = Model(self)
        delegate = Delegate(self.model)
        self.setItemDelegate(delegate)
        self.setModel(self.model)
        self.setEditTriggers(QtWidgets.QTableWidget.NoEditTriggers)
        for row in range(self.model.rowCount()):
            for column in range(self.model.columnCount()):
                index = self.model.index(row, column)
                self.openPersistentEditor(index)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    w = MyWindow()
    w.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Comment: Could you explain me better? What do you mean by "editing" in the case of QComboBox?

Comment: @eyllanesc I have added the reply to your uestion in the main post.

Comment: As you indicate to say that not a widget is not editable, it can have a different behavior depending on the widget, in the case of qcombobox I understand that it only implies that the selected item that involves deactivating the following behaviors does not change: 1) not handling the arrow keys , 2) when the click is made, the popup should not be shown, is there any other case? I am right? I have changed the title since making a widget not editable is too broad, in the case of QComboBox it is limited.

Comment: @eyllanesc ComboBox is just an example. I just want a readonly view of the data, where instead of using a plain QTableView to display, I have fancy widgets which provide better data visualization. The displayed content of the widget should not be editable by the user, and obviously the model data shouldn't be either. This is what I want to achieve, for every widget I want to use, not just ComboBox.
In ComboBox, I'd prefer the popup not be shown, but that's a plus. If the user can't select a different item from the popup I'll be just fine.

Comment: If it is for all widgets then there is no answer since each widget is a special case. Maybe what you want is to disable the widget, try: widget.setDisabled(True).

Comment: Ok, then since I know how to handle the other ones I use I'll limit this to ComboBox. setDisable makes it hard to read, so I prefer to handle each case individually I guess.

Comment: Exactly, each widget is a special case

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Explanation:

Some concepts must be clarified:

- For Qt to disable editing that a view (QListView, QTableView, QTreeView, etc.) or item of the view implies only that the editor will not open through user events such as clicked, double-clicked, etc.
- The user interaction in Qt follows the following path:

  1. The user interacts through the OS with the mouse, keyboard, etc.
  2. the OS notifies Qt of that interaction.
  3. Qt creates [`QEvent`](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qevent.html)s and sends it to the widgets.
  4. The widget analyzes what you should modify regarding the [`QEvent`](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qevent.html) you receive.

In your case, using [`openPersistentEditor()`](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qabstractitemview.html#openPersistentEditor) shows the widgets, and so the edibility from the Qt point of view is not valid for this case.

### Solution:

Considering the above a possible general methodology to make a widget not editable: block some point of the user-widget interaction path. In this case, the simplest thing is to prevent the widget from receiving the [`QEvent`](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qevent.html)s through an event filter.

Considering the above, the solution is:

```py
class DisableEventsManager(QtCore.QObject):
    def __init__(self, *, qobject, events=None, apply_childrens=False):
        if not isinstance(qobject, QtCore.QObject):
            raise TypeError(
                f"{qobject} must belong to a class that inherits from QObject"
            )
        super().__init__(qobject)

        self._qobject = qobject
        self._events = events or []

        self._qobject.installEventFilter(self)
        self._children_filter = []
        if apply_childrens:
            for child in self._qobject.findChildren(QtWidgets.QWidget):
                child_filter = DisableEventsManager(
                    qobject=child, events=events, apply_childrens=apply_childrens
                )
                self._children_filter.append(child_filter)

    @property
    def events(self):
        return self._events

    @events.setter
    def events(self, events):
        self._events = events
        for child_filter in self._children_filter:
            child_filter.events = events

    def eventFilter(self, obj, event):
        if self.events and self._qobject is obj:
            if event.type() in self.events:
                return True
        return super().eventFilter(obj, event)
```

```
def createEditor(self, parent, option, index):
    combo = QtWidgets.QComboBox(parent)
    combo.addItems(["", "Cat", "Dog"])
    combo_event_filter = DisableEventsManager(qobject=combo)
    combo_event_filter.events = [
        QtCore.QEvent.KeyPress,
        QtCore.QEvent.FocusIn,
        QtCore.QEvent.MouseButtonPress,
        QtCore.QEvent.MouseButtonDblClick,
    ]
    return combo
```