# pyqt performance issues on dynamic widget array-like table

Tags: pyqt, pyqt5

I have a GUI that uses a custom QStyledItemDelegate, QTableView and QAbstractModel to display records that I load at startup.

Each record is displayed as a row of widgets. Each column is associated with a specific widget type. I.e. a QDateEdit, a QTimeEdit, a couple of QLineEdit, 3 QComboBox.

If I try to load ~2500 records the GUI takes a lot of time to load, as well as adapt to changes when some of the filters are used. Scrolling is not excessively bad though, so I suspect I might be doing things inefficiently when it comes to add or remove widget rows.

Row addition is always an append. Row deletion can happen everywhere.

These are the implementation in my model:

```py
    def row_append(self, count=1, parent=QtCore.QModelIndex()):
        rows = self.rowCount()
        last = rows + count - 1
        self.layoutAboutToBeChanged.emit()
        self.beginInsertRows(parent, rows, last)
        self.insertRows(rows, count, parent) # Implemented in my model
        self.endInsertRows()
        self.layoutChanged.emit()
        for column in range(self.columnCount()):
            self.table_view.enable_cell(rows, column)
        return self.rowCount() - count



    def row_delete(self, row, count=1, parent=QtCore.QModelIndex()):
        last = row + count - 1
        self.layoutAboutToBeChanged.emit()
        self.beginRemoveRows(parent, row, last)
        self.removeRows(row, count, parent)  # Implemented in my model
        self.endRemoveRows()
        self.layoutChanged.emit()
```

The implementation details of my version of insertRows and removeRows are not relevant, as I can deal with that.

If I receive 500 inserts or 351 deletes, I will call these functions.

My issue is if this is how it's supposed to be done when you get a huge batch of things that causes most of what's currently being displayed to change.

I remember reading that if you have to make big changes, it might be easier to destroy everything and rebuild from scratch, but:

1. Am I using the wrong approach (e.g. functions used and implemented) to destroy everything? Similarly for when I rebuild everything from scratch.
2. Could it be that I'm trying to build something too heavy for pyqt?

Comment: It seems likely that creating all those widgets is the main bottleneck. I suggest you use the [profile module](https://docs.python.org/3/library/profile.html) to confirm that. If you want custom cell editors, the most efficient way to achieve that for large tables is with [item delegates](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/model-view-programming.html#delegate-classes).

Comment: Looking at the link about delegates it seems to me I'm already doing what you are suggesting. I have a custom QStyledItemDelegate that handles my widgets on behalf o my QTableView. If there's some difference in what I'm doing and what you are suggesting, could you please be more explicit? @ekhumoro

Comment: Your questions states: "Each record is displayed as a row of widgets". So I naturally assumed that you are creating all the widgets up front. Item delegates can be used for many different things (not just custom editors), and your question doesn't state what you are using them for. I also have no idea what you mean by "handles my widgets on behalf of my QTableView". So: are you creating all the widgets up front, or not? And have have done the necessary profiling to confirm that that is the performance bottleneck? (NB: nobody else can do this for you, since you haven't provided an mvce).

Comment: Maybe it's easier if you check [this link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58250309/prevent-combobox-editing-in-styleditemdelegate), the code there shows what I am doing in regard to model-table-delegate. As for performance, yes, my issue lies with the pyqt side of things. I am not particularly happy with some of the design choices I made on the non pyqt code, but I was restricted by the pyqt layer (possibly because I'm still new to it). This is why I'm asking if the approach in the code I showed in my original post is optimal or not.